# Use fields from a template DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to make a simple application C# with docusign.
I created a template on the site with several fields that the user will have to fill in. The application simply chooses the email address of the candidate.

I do like this for create my Envelope :

```
TemplateRole tRoleSigner = new TemplateRole();
tRoleSigner.Email = DSConfig.Signer1Email;
tRoleSigner.Name = DSConfig.Signer1Name;
tRoleSigner.RoleName = "Candidat"; 
TemplateRole tRoleCC = new TemplateRole();
tRoleCC.Email = DSConfig.Cc1Email;
tRoleCC.Name = DSConfig.Cc1Name;
tRoleCC.RoleName = "EnCopie"; 

List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRoleSigner, tRoleCC };
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = "Signatures des documents relatifs à une promesse d'embauche",
    TemplateRoles = rolesList,
    TemplateId = DSConfig.TemplateID,
    Status = "sent"
};
```

I tested but the fields do not appear on the document ...

However if I directly use the template via docusign the fields are there!

I know that we can create a tab in the C # code but I want to use the fields defined on the site!

I think I'm missing something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, including logs and IDs can't be sure what is the issue.

Possibilities:

1. RoleName is wrong/mismatch. Must be the one in the template that you use the ID for.
2. Fields are using anchor tags that are not found in document.
3. Template is in production and you are using developer account.

You can also try the web app ("directly") again and enable to see the  API logs. The web app uses the same API that you do, and this way you can see exactly how it's done.

Comment: RoleNames are correct. I'm currently use a developer account but I don't see the  "production". I'll follow that point and edit the post if that's not it

Comment: Ok I understand, I'm so confused, I have 2 DocuSign Account with the same address... If I create the template on the other that works fine...

Comment: templates are for a specific account, you cannot use a template from account A with account B